# Matlab metaprograming: is there a method_missing equivalent as in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, matlab, metaprogramming

In Matlab, if you call an undefined method on an object, Matlab gives an error, e.g.:

```
No appropriate method, property, or field 'bar' for class 'Foo'.
```

In Ruby, it is possible to define a special method, called `method_missing`, on an object. If you then call a undefined method on that object, `method_missing` is called instead of a `NoMethodError` exception being raised. This is used for various kinds of metaprogramming.

Is there an equivalent in Matlab?

Comment: May I ask what the purpose is? What do you want `method_missing` to do? There might be workarounds for this? Also, is this OOP, with classes, objects etc?

Comment: To be honest, curiosity. I'm learning about matlab object oriented programming, and what are the different ways to do things.

Comment: Also: I like matlab tables for data analysis, and I was wondering if I could make matlab class which just contains one table and then adds methods useful for a table (e.g. `plot` , which creates a graph of the table with sensible defaults like the using the `VariableNames` property for the legend etc). Then, any method which the object doesn't know gets passed straight to the table contained in the object. Probably there is a more idiomatic matlab way  to do this, I'm not sure.

Comment: I guess that none of the answers I offered were satisfying. While deleting them as useless, can't help but answering your (rhetorical) question: no, there is no "method_missing" event in MATLAB; that's a thrown exception. Suggestion: when in Ruby program as in Ruby, when in MATLAB program as in MATLAB.

Comment: CST-Link --- I was busy the last week, and didn't get a chance to review them properly, I would like to read them.